# Iterating of a simple hello world program with llvm

Tags: c++, llvm

I am new to llvm framework and I am starting very basic. What's more basic than a hello world?
I want to iterate over my main function in main.c. It looks like the section
"Iterating over the BasicBlock in a Function" would be a good place to start"

```
Function &Func = ...
for (BasicBlock &BB : Func)
// Print out the name of the basic block if it has one, and then the
// number of instructions that it contains
errs() << "Basic block (name=" << BB.getName() << ") has "
         << BB.size() << " instructions.\n";
```

What do I set `Function &Func =` 
to?
I want to look at the main function in my main.c file.

While we're on this topic. What would I set `BasicBlock& BB = ...` to?

My code.

```
 bool Prereqs::runOnModule(Module &M) {
 /* Add your code here */
 errs() << "Hi: ";
 errs().write_escaped(M.getName()) << '\n';
 NumOfFunctions +=10;
 outs()<<"get opcode yields: getOpcode()" <<"\n";
 Function &Func = main.c;
       for (BasicBlock &BB : Func)

  // Print out the name of the basic block if it has one, and then the
                 //   // number of instructions that it contains
                 //     errs() << "Basic block (name=" << BB.getName() << ") has "
                 //                  << BB.size() << " instructions.\n";


print(M);
return false;
}
```

documentation
https://releases.llvm.org/8.0.0/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#basic-inspection-and-traversal-routines

Comment: There is no question here that is specific to llvm. The C++ tag is also debatable given the one file you name is a C file.

Comment: How so? I am asking how to iterate over a main.c file using llvm. Considering I am using c++ to examine a c file I am okay with it. Thanks for you critique though.

Comment: You're also using an editor to type your code and a web browser to read SO, that doesn't make the [webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webkit) or [emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emacs) tags relevant. Tags are supposed to be material to the question, not random bystanders.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to set `Func` to the return value of [Module::getFunction()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html#a209a615a3a32241323420cca24b5520a) and if you don't know what a Module is or how to make one, [there is a tutorial](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/index.html).